# activate geolocalisation on embed map

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, geolocation

I've embedded this map on my AIR app using StageWebView.

The javascript code provided by marinetraffic.com is this one :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    width='100%';       // the width of the embedded map in pixels or percentage
    height='450';       // the height of the embedded map in pixels or percentage
    border='1';     // the width of the border around the map (zero means no border)
    shownames='false';  // to display ship names on the map (true or false)
    latitude='37.4460'; // the latitude of the center of the map, in decimal degrees
    longitude='24.9467';    // the longitude of the center of the map, in decimal degrees
    zoom='9';       // the zoom level of the map (values between 2 and 17)
    maptype='3';        // use 0 for Normal map, 1 for Satellite, 2 for Hybrid, 3 for Terrain
    trackvessel='0';    // MMSI of a vessel (note: vessel will displayed only if within range of the system) - overrides "zoom" option
    fleet='';       // the registered email address of a user-defined fleet (user's default fleet is used)
    remember='false';   // remember or not the last position of the map (true or false)
    language='en';      // the preferred display language
    showmenu=true;      // show or hide the map options menu
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.marinetraffic.com/js/embed.js"></script>
```

Is it possible to add the current position of the user on this map ?

if so, how can I do it ?

(I've tried to add this in my script :

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };

      infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
      infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
  }
}
```

but it doesn't work).

Thx

Comment: It looks like the embed map from Marine Traffic doesn't expose the `map` object.

Comment: So, impossible to able the Geolocation ?